# Are these 23 a copy of the Tibetan Perfection of Knowledge Collection?

Tags: the-buddha, tibetan-buddhism, religion

I am new to Tibetan but am interested in the Tibetan script versions of the texts. Not knowing much Tibetan script yet, I am not totally sure I am looking at the right thing and so wanted to clarify to see if these 23 items are the Perfection of Knowledge collection.

The list of titles in Tibetan script I have found [here](http://read.84000.co/section/O1JC114941JC14665.html). The first two or three I have found (I think) the corresponding Tibetan script text [here](https://github.com/7-rabbit/riff-text/tree/master/content/kangyur) (འབུམ། and ཉི་ཁྲི།, basically). In [that](https://github.com/7-rabbit/riff-text/tree/master/content/kangyur) collection, does it contain all 23 of these texts? If so, where would I find them? If not, do they exist elsewhere online in Tibetan etexts?

If it's too complicated, primarily I'm interested if this collection has the 8000 line one, such as [here](https://github.com/7-rabbit/riff-text/tree/master/content/kangyur/%E0%BC%A0%E0%BC%A7%20%20%E0%BD%A4%E0%BD%BA%E0%BD%A2%E0%BC%8B%E0%BD%95%E0%BE%B1%E0%BD%B2%E0%BD%93%E0%BC%8B%E0%BD%A6%E0%BE%A3%E0%BC%8B%E0%BD%9A%E0%BD%BC%E0%BD%82%E0%BD%A6%E0%BC%8D)?